# Very poor performance of ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

I'm having a problem with an application I made for my company. We are taking queries out of an ERP system. People can search for an article, and then the application shows them all relevant technical data, pictures and/or datasheets.

Problem is: it's loading very slow. Queries seem to run fine, but the generation of the view takes ages.

This is my search code (don't mind the Dutch parts):

```
public IQueryable<Item> GetItems(string vZoekString)
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        //Split de ZoekString
        var searchTerms = vZoekString.ToLower().Split(null);

        // TODO: alles in een db query 
        //Resultaten oplijsten
        var term = searchTerms[0];
        var results = db.item_general.Where(c => c.ITEM.Contains(term) || c.DSCA.Contains(term));

        //Zoeken op alle zoektermen
        if (searchTerms.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < searchTerms.Length; i++)
            {
                var tempTerm = searchTerms[i];
                results = results.Where(c => c.ITEM.Contains(tempTerm) || c.DSCA.Contains(tempTerm));
            }
        }

        //Show
        return results;
```

And then, these results are returned to the view like this:

```
public ActionResult SearchResults(string vZoekString, string filterValue, int? pageNo)
    {
        //Bewaking zoekstring
        if (vZoekString != null)
        {
            pageNo = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vZoekString = filterValue;
        }

        //De zoekstring doorgeven
        if (vZoekString == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ZoekString = vZoekString;
        }

        //Ophalen Items via Business-Object
        //var vItems = new SearchItems().GetItems(vZoekString);
        SearchItems vSearchItems = new SearchItems();

        IQueryable<Item> vItems = vSearchItems.GetItems(vZoekString);

        //Nummering
        int pageSize = 10;
        int page = (pageNo ?? 1);

        //Show
        return View(vItems.OrderBy(x => x.ITEM).AsNoTracking().ToPagedList(page, pageSize));
    }
```

What can be wrong in my situation? Am I overlooking something?

**UPDATE:**

I've checked my code, and it seems that everything works very quickly, but it takes more than 10 seconds when it reaches `.ToPagedList()`. So my guess is that there is something wrong with that. I'm using the paged list from Nuget.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I would advice on using english names in variable names and comments, because it will make easier understand what you try to accomplish. Phrases like "Resultaten oplijsten" or "Zoeken op alle zoektermen" would need a translation.

Comment: Set a breakpoint before `return View` in order to determine, how long the collection of data takes and how much the view generation. If the most time consuming is indeed the view rendering, better post some of your View's code, because the problem is obviously there, then.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't evaluate your view code without seeing it the problem could very well be in the database query.
An IQueryable does not actually load anything from the database until you use the results. So the database query will only be run after the View code has started.

Try changing the View call to:

```
var items = vItems.OrderBy(x => x.ITEM).AsNoTracking().ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
return View(items);
```

And then check to see if the View is still the bottleneck.

(This should probably be a comment instead, but I don't have the reputation....)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases where you face performance issues with MVC and EF it is due to returning entities to views and getting stung by lazy loading. The reason for this is that when ASP.Net is told to send an object to the browser it needs to serialize it. The process of serialization iterates over the entity which touches lazy-load proxies, triggering those related entities to load one at a time.

You can detect this by running a profiler against your database, set a breakpoint point prior to the end of your action, then watch what queries execute as the action call returns. Lazy loading due to serialization will appear as a number of individual (TOP 1) queries being executed in rapid succession after the action has completed prior to the page rendering.

The simplest suggestion to avoid this pain is *don't return entities from controllers.*

```
IQueryable<Item> vItems = vSearchItems.GetItems(vZoekString);
var viewModels = vItems.OrderBy(x => x.ITEM)
    .Select(x => new ItemViewModel
    {
       ItemId = x.ItemId,
       // .. Continue populating view model. If model contains a hierarchy of data, map those to related view models as well.
    }).ToPagedList(page, pageSize);

return View(viewModels);
```

The benefit of this approach:

1. The `.Select()` will result in a query that only retrieves the data you actually need to populate the view models. (The data your view needs) Faster query, less data across the wire between DB server -> App server -> Browser
2. This doesn't result in any lazy loads.

The caveat of this approach:

1. You need to take care that the `.Select()` expression will go to SQL, so no .Net or private functions for stuff like translating/formatting data. Populate raw values into the view model then expose properties on the view model to do the translation which will serialize that formatted data to the client. Basic stuff like `FullName = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName` is fine, but avoid things like `OrderDate = DateTime.Parse(x.DateAsISO)` if the DB stored dates as strings for example.

You can leverage mappers like Automapper to assist with mapping between Entity and ViewModel. Provided the mapping tool inspects/traverses the destination to populate rather than the source, you should be good. Automapper does support integration within `IQueryable` so it would be a worthwhile investment to research that if you want to leverage a mapper.